# Ways of computing $\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}dx\cot(x/2)\sin(n\pi x/\beta)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been trying to compute the following integral related to a different problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614793/how-do-i-solve-this-integral-equation) and give it a more pliable form. I converged after some complex analysis related computation to the following form

$$C_n=\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}dx\cot(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{\pi nx}{\beta})=2\beta ((-1)^n+\frac{2n}{\pi\lambda^2}\phi_n)$$

where $\lambda=\frac{\beta}{\pi}$ and $|\beta|<\pi$ and
$$\phi_n=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\lambda\pi m)}{m(m+\frac{n}{\lambda})}$$

which I know can be written in terms of the Lerch transcedent. The complex analysis calculation was done strictly speaking under the assumption that $n>0$, but it is obvious that $C_n=-C_{-n}$ and I thought that the expression for the coefficient should satisfy this constraint but $\phi_n$ does not seem to obey the correct constraint.

Question:

1) Is the above formula correct?

a) If yes, what gives in the naive contradiction above?

b) If no, what is the correct form for this integral and a way to find it?

I have worked on this for a bit and I don't seem to figure out what's amiss.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

Start with $x=iy$ and $\frac{\pi n} \beta=k $
$$\int\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sin (k x)\,dx=i \int\coth \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \sinh (k y)\,dy$$
$$2\int\coth \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \sinh (k y)\,dy=B_{e^y}(1-k,0)+B_{e^y}(-k,0)-B_{e^y}(k,0)-B_{e^y}(k+1,0)$$ which makes the definite integral
$$2\int_{-a}^a\coth \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin (k y)\,dy$$ to be 
$$\Big[B_{e^{-a}}(k,0)+B_{e^{-a}}(k+1,0)+B_{e^a}(1-k,0)+B_{e^a}(-k,0)\Big]-$$
$$\Big[B_{e^a}(k,0)+B_{e^a}(k+1,0)+B_{e^{-a}}(1-k,0)+B_{e^{-a}}(-k,0)\Big]$$

Comment: What is the definition of this function $B_t(x,y)$? Is it a Bell polynomial?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg. The beta function.